# Get the name attached to an ORCID ID through some API without Institution credentials

Tags: orcid

I have an ORCID number but my institution is not a "member".
I'm editing Proceedings where each author has supplied eir ORCID numbers and I would like to check that these are correct. Instead of typing about 60 names into the [www.orcid.org](http://www.orcid.org) search interface, is there some way to do this through an API? (I can program in Perl, Python, PHP.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was easier than I thought. All you need is to use the URL `http://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000` with the ORCID ID instead of the zeros, and you receive a file containing the name of the owner of that ID.

Here is Perl code to do it (`$ORCID` contains the ID for which we seek the owner):

```
system("wget -O tmp -q http://orcid.org/$ORCID");
open IN, "tmp";
binmode IN, ":utf8";
while (<IN>) {
if (m/<meta property="og:title" content="(.+?) \([0-9X-]{19}\)">/) { $name=$1; }
}
close IN;
print $name;
```